# Windows Hello only allows Security Key and no PIN or Fingerprint

Tags: google-chrome, security, windows-hello

I'm trying to use Windows Hello as an authentication 2FA website (Duo) and the only authentication option I get is by a security key - [image: See example]
although I do have my PIN and fingerprint [configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxTxp.png)  in settings.

How can I allow chrome to use these options instead?

Comment: Did you _register_ first?

Comment: My mistake, that site actually works, but the 2FA service I'm using (Duo) doesn't. I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: So maybe that service is implementing WebAuthN incorrectly by not registering the user (you) first.

Comment: Based on the fact that it's working on my friend's laptop, I'm inclined to assume that the implementation is correct, and there's something wrong with my PC.

Comment: What icons are being displayed on the logon screen?  You should see the (security key symbol, the Windows Hello pin icon, the Windows Hello Fingerprint, and the Password icon).  Please [edit] your question and provide an appropriate screenshot

Comment: Are you trying to perform a WebAuthn password-less login or do you use it as second factor?